# External loss function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a simple 2 layer dense NN which I want to use a regression model to compute 4 number of given `~ 700` features of an image. Unfortunately, I do not have ground truth elements, so I use custom loss function. Here's the source of the function:

```
def loss_function(logits, img, g, compare_img):

    final_img = img_pipeline(vga_8b=img, g=g%external color gamma function%)

    with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
        loss = score(gt_image=compare_img, curr_img=final_img)
        return loss
```

Where `logits` are the current evaluated 4 numbers, g is just a interpolated function used as color gamma for the image, img is external grayscale image used to generate the final result image used for the `score` function. `compare_img` is not a ground truth image, but some statistical values `(kept in python dict)` used in the score function to evaluate the current produced image.
Unfortunately, I can't feed `g` and `compare_img` as they are python function and python dictionary which cannot be converted to tensors.

Is there a way to hack it somehow and achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use external functions with tensorflow with `tf.map` but I'm afraid to to say, that these are not able to calculate gradients through it. but you loss functions needs to be derivable in every case. So you have to write the function in tensorflow.

For your dict values you can create a  lookuptable with

`table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(
  tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys, values), -1)`